DBeaver - Salesforce JDBC - end-user denied authorization
I get the error "end-user denied authorization" from DBeaver when trying to connect to Salesforce.
I have admin access to salesforce.
Here are the steps I took to get this far:

set up connected App for DBeaver in Salesforce.
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.c360_a_set_up_dbeaver_connected_app.htm&type=5

Connect to DBeaver to Data cloud
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.c360_a_dbeaver_to_cdp.htm&type=5


I can see in salesforce login history that my log in is successful so I am not sure where this issue is caused.  Any help with that would be great.

Take a look here: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000A7uTVSAZ. Someone from SalesForce say: Based on the error, the user profile is missing the permission set for "Data Cloud Admin". Once you apply this permission set, this should go away.
